# Optimize Exchange Flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency-exchange-rates

im actually working in ruby on rails and im watching methods that convert values according to specific exchange rate.
For example, for each value of an account, it makes the following execution:

```
@accounts.examplevalue = @params["examplevalue"].to_f * currency_exchange_rate.to_f
```

And "currency_exchange_rate" is calculated according to different ways, like taking the exchange rate from database instead of api calls or excel upload.

My question is: do you know other ways that can optimize the full process without moltiply each single value for "currency_exchange_rate"? Maybe like calling '@accounts.examplevalue_converted'?
Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve and why? Please elaborate on that `currency_exchange_rate` calculations.

Comment: @stolarz I would like to avoid multiplying the value by the exchange rate each time. I would like it to iterate automatically within accounts and the values to be accessible at all times, perhaps in a separate helper. Right now all multiplications are performed in the same way but in different controllers.

Comment: So I guess you need method in a model, assuming that `currency_exchange_rate` is one of the field of your model:
```def converted_value(value)
  value * currency_exchange_rate
end```
and then you can use it like `@accounts.converted_value(@params["examplevalue"].to_f)`

Comment: _"for each value of an account, it makes the following execution"_ – some explanation would probably help to understand what you are trying to achieve. What kind of values are these? Why do you have to multiply each value with an exchange rate?